# background URL not displaying

Tags: html, css, background-image

```css
.w { 
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg'); 
}
```

```html
<button class="w drum">w</button>
```

I have been trying to use my Atom editor to create background images for my website and it hasn't been working but we I should use it inline on the HTML file, it will work, I won't to use it on the HTML file. I want to keep the file separate from each other. Please I need your assistance

Comment: As I see the background image is set as the background of the button, but it is too big. You should set the background-position, background-repeat and background-size attributes also to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

This could fix your issue!
`background-size: contain/cover`

Contain will scale the image and fit it to inside the button. Cover will cover the whole button. Or you can try `background-size: 100% 100%;`

```css
.w { 
  background: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/soap-bubble-1958650_960_720.jpg') no-repeat; 
  background-size: cover;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button class="w drum">w</button>
```

Comment: I have tried that now, still not showing as a background image with CSS but when I do this,     <button style="background-image:url('images/tom1.png')" class="w drum">w</button>
it work but I don't want to use inline CSS

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload your CSS file manually, Or remove cached data.

If you are programming in PHP,

Do it like this:

```
<link href="style.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: @user8492395 , first of all , load `http://yourwebsite.com/path/to/style.css` and refresh, then load `http://yourwebsite.com/path/to/page.html`

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of your image folder, if you are inserting your images(downloaded) in a separate CSS file then your image folder should be inside the CSS folder.

```
.w { 
  background-image: url('images/pic.png')
}
```